# Relationship between Gamma and chi squared distributions

Tags: distributions, gamma-distribution, chi-squared-distribution

What is the relationship between the Gamma distribution and the chi-squared distribution?

Answer (score 0):

If a Chi-Squared distribution has $p$ degrees of freedom, then this is identical to a Gamma$(\frac{p}{2},2)$ distribution.